How to keep whitespace in slot components in Vue 3?
I am creating a custom component to replace <pre> with some extra style.
The code below will preserve the 4 spaces (indentation):
<pre>
    test();
</pre>

However when using my custom component, the whitespace is lost:
<CustomCodeBlock>
    test();
</CustomCodeBlock>

My component uses <pre> internally though:
<pre><code><slot /></code></pre>

How can I preserve the whitespace when using my custom component?

This is a result of the Vue compiler not preserving whitespace.  You can change this behavior in vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          whitespace: 'preserve'
        }
      }
    }),
  ]
})


Can I change this per component? I don't want to impact the rest of my app.
